# Vector error correction model

Tags: vector-error-correction-model

[image: VECM]

I investigate the relationship among 3 variables (XMIN, LPIB, LIPI). I found that all variables are stationnary in their first differences. Johansen's cointegration method has been adopted to examine the long run relationship among the variables. I found that there is one cointegrating vector in the model.

Now, it is convenient to make the test based on vector error correction models (VECM), so I made the test with Eviews and I don't know how to interpret the table.

Comment: I don't see a table with the test results. The one included looks like estimation output for an unrestricted VECM. Also, what is the actual question? First you ask about interpreting the error correction term, then you ask about interpreting the results of a Granger causality test.

Comment: Oh, and your title does not quite match the content. Consider adapting it to make it more informative and to the point.

Comment: the table is above represent the VECM. My question is how to interpret this table

Comment: After the edit you are referring to *the test* in the last paragraph; however, it is not clear *what* test that is. The last paragraph still does not quite make sense, since you refer to a test you did but do not present its results. The table contains estimated model coefficients with their significances and model diagnostics such as $R^2$, AIC and other. Please elaborate on which part of the table is unclear.

Comment: I mean the middle part of the table: How can i elaborate the short-run model that is to express each variable with others ( for exemple to express the PIB with XMIN and IPI). i learned in many articles that i must should the equation which have a negative coeff of Coin Eq 1

Comment: You can read the table as follows: here is the first column: $\Delta PIB_t=0.0069ect_{t-1}+0.1567\Delta PIB_{t-1}+0.2781\Delta PIB_{t-2}-0.0027\Delta LXMIN_{t-1}-0.0137\Delta LXMIN_{t-2}-0.0810\Delta LIPI_{t-1}-0.0839 \Delta LIPI_{t-2}+0.0056+\varepsilon_t$ where $ect_t=1.0000\cdot LPIB_{t-1}-0.4173LXMIN_{t-1}+2.9926LIPI_{t-1}-0.0204trend-21.0302$. Is that what you need?

Comment: Did you get your question answered, or did you just get fed up? :)

Comment: i appreciate your help, your answer will help me a liitle bit :)

Comment: @RichardHardy, if that is the information the OP needs, why not turn that into an official answer?

Comment: @gung, it is unclear to me what the OP needs, but perhaps it is worthwhile turning that into an answer nevertheless...

Answer (score 1):

Still having some doubts over what your question really is, I will convert a comment that you found helpful to an answer.

You can read the middle part of the table as follows:

$$ 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta PIB_t &= 0.0069ect_{t−1} \\
             &+ 0.1567 \Delta PIB_{t−1}+0.2781 \Delta PIB_{t−2} \\
             &− 0.0027 \Delta LXMIN_{t−1}−0.0137 \Delta LXMIN_{t−2} \\
             &− 0.0810 \Delta LIPI_{t−1}−0.0839 \Delta LIPI_{t−2} \\
             &+ 0.0056+\varepsilon_t 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

where

$$ 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
ect_{t-1} &= 1.0000⋅LPIB_{t−1}−0.4173LXMIN_{t−1}+2.9926LIPI_{t−1}−0.0204(t-1) \\
          &- 21.0302. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$